# how do I use numpy find consequent same elements and the index under some condition?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's suppose I have two numpy.array():

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]) #index

b = np.array([1,1,4,3,3,3,5,2,2,2,2,6])    #element
```

How do I efficiently find all consequent same element whose number of consequent same element >=3 , the start_index and end_index? I hope the result :

```
c:  array([4,8])  #start_index
d:  array([6,11]) #end_index
e:  array([3,2])  #consequent same values whose number of consequent same element >=3
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the question "...find all consequent same element whose number of consequent same element >=3 ...". It is unclear how the indexes from the arrays c and d are related to a, b and e

Comment: @NileshIngle I want to deal with time series problem，the a represents time series and the b represents values. Sorry,my English is bad,I am Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

Find the group boundaries:

```
sw, = np.where(np.diff(b, prepend=1, append=1))
```

Filter for condition:

```
cm, = np.where(np.diff(sw)>=3)
```

Retrieve corresponding indices

```
c = a[sw[cm]]
d = a[sw[cm+1]-1]
```

and values

```
e = b[sw[cm]]
```

Admire

```
c
# array([4, 8])
d
# array([ 6, 11])
e
# array([3, 2])
```

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-f3f81fe2743b> in <module>()
      1 b = np.array(df['b'])
      2 a = np.array(df['a'])
----> 3 sw, = np.where(np.diff(b, prepend=1, append=1))
      4 cm, = np.where(np.diff(sw)>=3)
      5 c = a[sw[cm]]

TypeError: diff() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prepend'

Comment: @BingoSun Old numpy version? You can either upgrade or work around by prepending and appending yourself: `np.r_[1, <result from diff>, 1]`